# How to replace the property of the object dynamically in angualrjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
var $scope.form = {
    Name: "",
    fields: []
}
angular.forEach($scope.form.fields, function (f) {
    if (f.hasOwnProperty('order')) {
        //code to replace the value of the property
    } else {
        //if order is not present push the new values to the $scope.form.fields.
    }
});
```

I have a pop up their I am appending textboxes.When i append one text box,I am pushing the object to $scope.form.fields i.e.,Name,id,order..When i append the second textbox it is itering 2 times and getting 3 textboxes displayed. Its getting doubled for every new textbox.So I thought when `$scope.form.fields` contains order i should have a right to change the name of the textbox.If its not present i'l just push those new object into $scope.form.fields.Can anyone give a solution for it .

Comment: `f.order = "The Value"`

Comment: But i am changing the value of it dynamically in the popup

Comment: ohk..but its working..I just gave a console statement in that and entered values manually into the $scope.form.fields.Then it worked.so only i approached for that..is there any other option to solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're having an array ie `fields` and you need to push the new values when array doesn't already contain the same. You can use either `indexOf` or `inArray` functions of array. Try below snippet

```
angular.forEach($scope.form.fields, function (f, key) {
    if (f.indexOf('order') >= 0) { // check whether array contains `order` or not
        $scope.form.fields[key]['order'] = 'new value';
    } else {
        $scope.form.fields.push('new value');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have posted it because i dont know how to attempt it..So only i have asked what to do for replacing and how to push to it

Comment: some where it depends upon what you are pushing into this array. I need to see your array structure.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/X8p6UkOXDZS2Wg0JMU6v?p=preview

Look at this fiddle..its not working due to some including files....But see the addform.js..the logic is there.,..

Comment: once see the addform.js in the provided plunker.Based on it can u help me to solve this situation